# Filter multiple columns and apply a user function to all in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume we have a df as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1' :['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4'], 
                   'COL2' :['', 'A_1', 'B', 'A_2'],
                   'COL3' :['A_3', '', 'Q', 'J'],
                   'VALUES' :[1,2,3,4]})
print(df)
Col1 COL2 COL3  VALUES
0  A_1       A_3       1
1  A_2  A_1            2
2  A_3    B    Q       3
3  A_4  A_2    J       4
```

What I am trying to do is 1) filter all the columns start with 'COL' and then apply a user function to all of those filtered columns and clean them up. Here is the what I am doing:

```
def cleanup(val):
            for i in val:
                if "A_" in i:
                    return i
            return ""

#Filter all the columns start with COL
filter_routes_col = [col for col in df if col.startswith('COL')]
df[filter_routes_col] = df[filter_routes_col].apply(cleanup, axis=1)
```

But this seems to return the following err:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you want to apply `cleanup` function to every element, then use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is a straight choice:

```
def cleanup(val):
    return val if "A_" in val else "" 

df[filter_routes_col] = df[filter_routes_col].applymap(cleanup)
```

result:

```
  COL1 COL2 COL3  VALUES
0  A_1       A_3       1
1  A_2  A_1            2
2  A_3                 3
3  A_4  A_2            4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the result of

```py
df[filter_routes_col].apply(cleanup, axis=1)
```

You'll see that it just returns a single value for each row, which is the first value in the row which has `A_` in it:

```
0    A_1
1    A_2
2    A_3
3    A_4
```

One way to solve this is process all the values in the row in the `cleanup` function and return a list of results, which you can then use in `apply` with `result_type='expand'` to expand into the columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1' :['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4'], 
                   'COL2' :['', 'A_1', 'B', 'A_2'],
                   'COL3' :['A_3', '', 'Q', 'J'],
                   'VALUES' :[1,2,3,4]})

def cleanup(series):
    return [i if 'A_' in i else '' for i in series]

df[filter_routes_col] = df[filter_routes_col].apply(cleanup, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df
```

Output:

```
  COL1 COL2 COL3  VALUES
0  A_1       A_3       1
1  A_2  A_1            2
2  A_3                 3
3  A_4  A_2            4
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is for applying a function to an entire row or column. Here, you're applying a function to individual elements, so you should use `applymap`.

```
df = df[[col for col in df if col.startswith('COL')]].applymap(
    lambda x: x if ('A_1' in x) else '')
```

If you're cleaning up unreliable input, you might want to replace `col.startswith('COL')` with `str(col).startswith('COL')` so that if someone enters something other than a string as a column name, it won't return an error.